# Slider automatico com 5 colunas como fazer?

Tags: javascript, mobile, layout-responsivo, slider, owl-carousel

Estou tentando fazer um slider automatico nesse estilo, mas não está dando certo.

[image: Modelo de Slider]

```html
 <section class="mbr-section" id="equipe"
         style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); padding-top: 120px; padding-bottom: 120px;">
  
  <div class="list_carousel">

            <ul class="logos-slides owl-carousel owl-theme owl-responsive-992 owl-loaded" data-speed="500" data-items="6">
                        
                                   
             <div class="owl-stage-outer">
                 <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(60px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0.25s; width: 3052.8px;">
                       
                       <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 0px;">
                         <li style="height: 150px;"><a href="#" class="bwWrapper"><img src="assets/images/PM CONSULTORES/ Executivo.png" style="max-height:150px; width:auto" class="logo" width="2334" height="1630" alt="Nome"></a>                    
                         </li>
                       </div>
                        
                       <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 0px;">
                         <li style="height: 150px;"><a href="#" class="bwWrapper"><img src="assets/images/PM CONSULTORES/Executivo.png" style="max-height:150px; width:auto" class="logo" width="2334" height="1630" alt="Nome"></a>                    
                         </li>
                       </div>
                        
                       <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 0px;">
                         <li style="height: 150px;"><a href="#" class="bwWrapper"><img src="assets/images/PM CONSULTORES/ Executivo.png" style="max-height:150px; width:auto" class="logo" width="2334" height="1630" alt="Nome"></a>                    
                         </li>
                       </div> 
                        
                       <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 0px;">
                         <li style="height: 150px;"><a href="#" class="bwWrapper"><img src="assets/images/PM CONSULTORES/Executivo.png" style="max-height:150px; width:auto" class="logo" width="2334" height="1630" alt="Nome"></a>                    
                         </li>
                       </div>
                        
     </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="owl-controls"><div class="owl-nav"><div class="owl-prev" style="display: none;">prev</div><div class="owl-next" style="display: none;">next</div></div><div class="owl-dots" style=""><div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div><div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div></div></div></ul>
        </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isabela pelas classes que vc usou na sua pergunta estou vendo que vc está usando o Owl Carousel, para faze-lo funcionar na página vc precisa ajustar alguns detalhes na sua página. Link do projeto oficial com a documentação https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Primeiro vc precisa indexar o `.css` desse framework na `<head>` do seu documento. Nesse caso os links são do CDN, mas vc pode usar localmente usando o caminho dos arquivos no seu diretório.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
```

Depois no final do seu documento vc precisa adicionar os `<scripts>` do Owl

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Depois vc precisa colocar após esses script a sua configuração de como vc quer o Slider funcionando, deixei comentários no script pra te ajudar. Fiz nessa config para aparecer 2 imgs em telas pequenas 3 em médias e 5 em grandes.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
  });
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel({
      loop:true, //deixa ele rodando eternament
      margin:10, // distancia entre imgs
      autoplay:true, // fica rodando sozinho
      autoplayTimeout:1500, // tempo em que gira e para trocando imgs
      autoplayHoverPause:true, // no hover ele para de rodar
      responsive:{ 
      0:{
          items:2 // 2 img em telas até 767px
      },
      768:{
          items:3 // 3 img em telas maiores que 768px
      },
      992:{
          items:5 // 5 img em telas maiores que 992px
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

---

**Aqui tem o modelo completo da página pra vc ver** Repare que em telas pequenas tem só 2 imgs, mas execute em "Página toda" que vc vai ver 5 imgs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/200/100" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/200/100" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/200/100" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/200/100" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/200/100" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/200/100" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/200/100" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            nav: true,
            loop: true, //deixa ele rodando eternament
            margin: 10, // distancia entre imgs
            autoplay: true, // fica rodando sozinho
            autoplayTimeout: 1500, // tempo em que gira e para trocando imgsr
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 2 // 2 img em telas até 767px
                },
                768: {
                    items: 3 // 3 img em telas maiores que 768px
                },
                992: {
                    items: 5 // 5 img em telas maiores que 992px
                }
            }
        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigada Hugo, deu certo.

Comment: @Isabela Não deixe de ler a documentação oficial do Owl la tem coisas que podem te interessar. Boa sorte ai.